# Xamarin grid size problems when used with resized ImageButton (with AspectFit)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, grid, scale, imagebutton

What I want to have is two imageButtons side by side in a row matching the screen width in the bottom of the screen. I want aspect ratio to be the same no mater the size of a screen.

[I want it to look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZLG3.png)

I tried to achieve this using Grid. I have 2 ImageButton elements that have the same source image. Problem is when these images get resized down the height of a grid row doesn't wrap the new image height, when they get resized up they don't fill the whole screen width. It seems that the grid takes the height of an original image in both cases.

[Screen 1440 x 2960 in preview, when image is scaled down, grid height is bigger than it should be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vARr5.png)

[Screen 1800 x 2560 in preview, when image is supposed to be scaled up, but it seems that grid is clamping it to the original image height.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFKvG.png)

XAML:

```
<StackLayout 
Spacing="0">

<StackLayout
    VerticalOptions="Start">
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    BackgroundColor="Bisque"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <Grid x:Name="grid"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        ColumnSpacing="0"
        RowSpacing="0">

        <ImageButton
           x:Name="imageButton"                         
           Source="key1.png"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"/>

        <ImageButton                        
           Source="key1.png"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>

</StackLayout>
```

I found a workaround for when image is resized down:

```
imageButton.SizeChanged += (o, e) => 
        {
            grid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(imageButton.Height, GridUnitType.Absolute) });
        };
```

But this is not a solution I want (especially because it doesn't work in both cases). What am I missing? This shoulod be simple. Is this maybe not a grid problem but something else? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> I want aspect ratio to be the same no mater the size of a screen.

Try to give a `RowDefinition` and `ColumnDefinition` to the `Grid`. And set `VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"` to Grid to keep the imageButton fix at the bottom of the screen.:

```
<StackLayout 
        Spacing="0">

                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                     VerticalOptions="Start">
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Green"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                </StackLayout>



    <Grid x:Name="grid"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                        ColumnSpacing="0"
                        RowSpacing="0">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ImageButton
                        x:Name="imageButton"                         
                        Source="Images.png"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Aspect="AspectFill"/>

        <ImageButton                        
                        Source="Images.png"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1" 
                        Aspect="AspectFill"/>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I need my image to keep the aspect ratio. If i set imageButton Aspect to AspectFill it doesn't keep the aspect ratio, it stretches and crops the image. I did set `ColumnDefinition Width="50*"` and `RowDefinition Height="auto"`, but it doesn't work as I thought it would.

Comment: If you want to  keep the aspect ratio of your image, you should use `AspectFit` instead of `AspectFill`. `AspectFit`  : Scale the image to fit the view. Some parts may be left empty (letter boxing). And `AspectFill`: Scale the image to fill the view. Some parts may be clipped in order to fill the view.

Comment: I did use `AspectFit` and then i get the problem described above, where grid height takes original image height and not resized one.

Comment: I don't think  grid will take the resized height if you use AspectFit , image will be scaled not the grid.

Comment: Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Since you know the aspect ratio of your image and the width of the image is half of the screen width, you can calculate the height of the image. And then assign them to the imageButtons.